# Multiple check for empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a situation where I need to move the dataframe forward in code only if it is not empty. Illustrated below:

```
----- Filter 1 -------
Check if df.empty then return emptydf
else
----- Filter 2 ------
Check if df.empty then return emptydf
else
----- Filter 3 ------
return df
```

The code for the above is written as below(Just a part of code):

```
def filter_df(df):
    df = df[df.somecolumn > 2].copy()

    if df.empty:
        return df

    df = df[df.someother == 2].copy()

    if df.empty:
        return df

    df = df[df.all <= 10].copy()

    return df
```

If I have many such filters which expect dataframe not to be empty, I need to check empty after each filter. Is there any better way of checking dataframe empty rather than checking at each level.

Comment: can you load more data on the post like how your dataFrame looks like, What is the data source like csv , html or json etc, that will give more visibility and reproduce the dataset.

Comment: may be something like this , create a list of all your filters and name it `filter` then , `while not df.empty : for i in filters: df = i` and outside loop call the empty df.. obviously it would help if we get some data and filters to play around. :)

Comment: My dataframe has more than 60 columns and the filter is not as simple as shown. I just need a way to eliminate multiple empty checks

Comment: @pygo My data source is a csv.

Comment: @pygo My problem is not an empty check issue. It is its usage.

Comment: I understand that,its just precheck validation if your dataset really have epmty dataset it mostly based on usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly subsetting your dataframe is expensive. Repeatedly copying your dataframe may also be expensive. It's also expensive to pre-calculate a large number of Boolean masks. The tricky part is finding a way to apply the masks *lazily* in a `for` loop.

While the below functional solution may seem ugly, it does address the above concerns. The idea is to combine a Boolean mask iteratively with an aggregate mask. Check in your loop whether your *mask* has all `False` values, not whether a dataframe is empty. Apply the aggregate mask *once* at the end of your logic:

```
from operator import methodcaller

def filter_df(df):

    masks = [('somecolumn', 'gt', 2),
             ('someother', 'eq', 2),
             ('all', 'le', 10)]

    agg_mask = np.ones(len(df.index)).astype(bool)  # "all True" mask

    for col, op, val in masks:

        mask = methodcaller(op, val)(df[col])
        agg_mask = agg_mask & mask

        if not agg_mask.any():
            return df[agg_mask]

    return df[agg_mask]
```

Note for this solution series comparison operators such as `>`, `==`, `<=` have functional equivalents `pd.Series.gt`, `pd.Series.eq`, `pd.Series.le`.

Answer (score -2):

you can use function and call that after very filter

```
def check_empty(df):
    if df.empty:
       return df

df = df[df.somecolumn > 2].copy()

check_empty(df)

df = df[df.someother == 2].copy()

check_empty(df)

df = df[df.all <= 10].copy()

return df
```

Comment: Code shouldn't proceed if filter 1 returns empty

Comment: it will not proceed, because after each filter check control will visit function to check data frame is empty